# Does the Azure SDK for Java is enterprise/production ready?

Tags: java, azure

We are evaluating the Azure SDK for Java usage for one of our product. So I would like to know below details:

1. we did our prototype with version 0.7, does this version is stable release and production ready? why the major version is still zero? are they beta?
2. Our product's end users generate the certificates and provide to us, we store them in DB, I can't find the API which gets the certificate as in memory String/Stream. It demands to store it in a file and loads from there. Can I avoid certificate file storage into the disk?
3. Does the self-signed .PFX file format is supported or only JKS file?

Comment: This question is broad and unclear, and contains multiple questions. The Java SDK has been available for several years; not beta (feel free to examine [the sdk on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java) if you need to evaluate its implementation). If you have questions about manipulating certificates, ask in a separate question. No idea what you're asking about with avoiding disk storage (but again, make a separate question).

Comment: Thank you for the comments David, I corrected some typos now. I will post a separate question on the certification part. Can I be sure that the SDK is production ready?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the version 0.7 SDK is stable release for producton scenes. 
Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-download-mac/ for more information and feel free to let us know if you have any further inquiry.

For the second question - how to get the certificates form the String in Java. Please check below code and see if it helps:

```
KeyStore ks = null;
String certificateStr = "<cert string>";
String password = "<password>";
StringBufferInputStream sbis = null;
try {
     ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
     char[] passwordArray = password.toCharArray();
     sbis = new StringBufferInputStream(certificateStr);
     ks.load(sbis, passwordArray);
     sbis.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

For the third question, the .PFX format certificate file is supported on Azure. You may want to refer to the documents https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/ to know how to enable HTTPS for an APP in Azure and how to configure SSL for an APP in Azure.

Best Regards.

---

Sample code for comment 2:

```
String keyStoreName = "<keyStoreName>";
String password = "<password>";
URL url = new URL("<url string>");
// Get KeyStore
KeyStore ks = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    char[] passwordArray = password.toCharArray();
    fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(keyStoreName);
    ks.load(fis, passwordArray);
    fis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
// Get SSLSocketFactory
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(ks, password.toCharArray());
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
// Process GET Request
SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
InputStream responseStream = (InputStream) con.getContent();
String response = getStringFromInputStream(responseStream);
responseStream.close();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. 
1) happy that it is production ready - version number is confusing.

Comment: 2) I'm able to load the string into KeyStore, but how to use this KeyStore object to create com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration? I couldn't find an API for that so for.

As the below method accepts only file Path, it is forcing me to store the KeyStore into disk and load it from there.

Configuration myConfig = ManagementConfiguration.configure(new URI(baseURL), subscriptionId,keyStoreFilePath, keyStorePassword);

Are there any alternate APIs?

Comment: 3) Below link says, "need to convert that PFX into a JKS file, since that's what Java uses to authenticate via certificates."
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/
 
I have been facing "certificate not verified" exception when I used SDK 0.7, which leads me to ask this question.
When I used PFX with recent version of SDK 0.8 which was released last week, I'm not getting this exception thrown from the SDK. I can go with SDK 0.8 now.

Comment: @SakthiKumaranSuriya For 2) You can use the REST API via HttpRequest, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert. The sample code in the doc is writed in C#, so I added related code in Java into the post.

Comment: for point #2, the Azure SDK for Java is NOT useful, I should go with REST APIs directly then. Thanks for your time, Peter Pan.